# ListViewHitTestInfo.Item.SubItems.IndexOf gives wrong value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Listview in which I want to react when a user double clicks on the last column (index = 7 ).

I'm using the following code:

```
Point mousePos = this.lvInfo.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
ListViewHitTestInfo hitTest = this.lvInfo.HitTest(mousePos);
int columnIndex = hitTest.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hitTest.SubItem);
if (columnIndex == 7)
    MessageBox.Show("Test!");
```

I'm getting wrong values for columnIndex, and can't figure out why.
The values seem to change even if I always click on the same column.

Comment: I also tried this on the (single) click event. Same problem there.

Comment: I've tried your code as it is and it works fine, I always get the right column index. The only properties of the ListView I changed from default were View to Details and FullRowSelect to True otherwise I couldn't click on the other columns. Do you have any other non-default properties on your ListView?

Comment: Non which should influence this. But I found an solution ( see my answer )

Comment: (multiselect = false, Headerstyle = non clickable). But I'm using a custom extension of the ListView which enables double buffering and filters out the WM_ERASEBKGND message, for flicker reduction. Maybe this causes problems ?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea. If you're curious then temporarily comment out the extension and see if it works. Glad you found a solution though. You should mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I temporarily used a normal listview instead. Same problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried this different approach and it works just fine.

```
private void lvInfo_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.X = e.X;
    this.Y = e.Y;
}

private void lvInfo_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if double clicked on gas column open dialog for entering new gas value
    Point mousePos = new Point(this.X,this.Y);
    ListViewHitTestInfo info = lvInfo.HitTest(mousePos);
    int colNr = info.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(info.SubItem);
    if (colNr == 7)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the PointToClient Method doesn't work for my.

Comment: Edited my answer. This now works for X and Y position. Don't ask me why.

Comment: You beat me to it, I was just about to post my code that does it based on X/Y values. I'm always just a minute too slow. Anyway, congrat's on getting it working! :-)